# como guardar un documento creado en csv en una carpeta temporal

Tags: php, mvc, csv

hola a todos genero un documento csv pero al generarlo se guarda en la la carpeta de mi proyecto.
mi duda es como mandarlo a una carpeta tmp para que se guarde en esa carpeta
cabe mencionar que cree una carpeta tmp para poder ahi almacenarlo

[image: estructura de mi proyecto]

**mi codigo es el siguiente**

```
$file = fopen("../tmp/Document.csv", 'w');
        
        foreach ($Reportes as $reporte) {
            //put data into csv file
            fputcsv($file, $reporte);
        }
```

al colocar esa ruta en fopen me marca error y **no me lo genera**

como exportar el documento en mi carpeta tmp

[image: exportarlo a la carpeta tmp]

Comment: ¿Y no te sirve usar [tmpfile](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.tmpfile.php)?  Si esa ruta te da error será porque está mal (eso si aún ves los archivos en tu disco en la carpeta que supuestamente estan almacenados)

Comment: También te puede ser de utilidad [esta función](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) para que los guardes allí

Comment: @masterguru edie mi pregunta la edite para poder explicarme espero de su ayuda

Comment: ¿desde que archivo y carpeta estás ejecutando ese `fopen()`?